# REST Easy jackson custom ObjectMapper does not reflect in mulitple REST API calls

Tags: json, rest, jackson, resteasy

I want to customize ObjectMapper for RESTEasy to hide some fields from POJO dynamically. I extended JacksonProvider and overriden the writeTo method. I got the reference of the ObjectMapper and added the mixins annotations. Every time I send REST API call to server, the writeTo method gets invoked and based on some condition it sets mixins annotations. But it reflects only for the first time. IF I modify the mixin annotations it does not reflect at all in subsequent calls. Looks like RESTEasy clones and caches the ObjectMapper somewhere. How to solve this issue? Same thing I have to do it Xml as well.

```
@Provider
public class MyJacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider
{
    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object value, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, 
            MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) 
            throws IOException 
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = locateMapper(type, mediaType);

        mapper.setMixinAnnotations(someDynamicmixinAnnotations);

        super.writeTo(value, type, genericType, annotations, mediaType, httpHeaders, entityStream);
    }
}
```

Regards,
Abdun

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `locateMapper()`?

Comment: locateMapper(type, mediaType) is a method of the super class JacksonJsonProvider

Comment: What version of Jackson is running?  `setMixinAnnotations()` is deprecated in 2.5.  If that's not your problem (you're using a version earlier than 2.5) then you should try printing out `mapper.mixinCount()` and `findMixInClassFor()` and see if you can't figure out which object mapper instance you're getting and why it's not changing when you call `setMixinAnnotations()`

Comment: Hi, I am using jackson 2.6.1. It is still not working. I have checked both findmixInClassFor and mixinCount. Its showing properly in mapper object, but there is no effect in th output.

Comment: `setMixinAnnotations()` is deprecated, so try using `setMixins()` see if that makes a difference: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setMixInAnnotations-java.util.Map-

Comment: It seems likely that `locateMapper` will return a single instance of `ObjectMapper`, since the object mapper is intended to be reused